# spring ResponseEntity limitations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have following code (it's a method in a controller) to return search results.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/findproducts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<FindResponse> findproducts(
                @RequestParam(value = "regionId", required=true) String regionId,....)


          ResponseEntity<FindResponse> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<FindResponse>(result, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

          return responseEntity;
    }
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Cache-Control: no-store Date: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 17:45:27
GMT Pragma: no-cache Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

I am  executing the service via SOAP UI.
Service returns results if the search finds 2K results.
AFterwards, response it empty or truncated. 
In the RAW console, I am seeing improper JSON.

How to send larger payload?
Any compression is possible?
I am using spring 3.2 release

Comment: I never had this problem, but if there is a problem with size of the data, maybe you should consider changing your code? You can also check if Product object is not too big (maybe you are loading some other unnecessary informations from database to it in this case create a DTO and send it. Unfortunately it requires rewriting objects.

Comment: All information is needed and required.  Wondering other options.

Comment: What server are you using? Maybe there are some limitations for data size...

Comment: weblogic 10.3 wih default configurations. JVM at Mx at 1024m.

Comment: My dev server is not available on intranet.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Date: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 17:45:27 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

Comment: Expiration date is weird :)

Comment: @VenkataMarrapu Please add that data to your post (use the edit link), rather than as a comment.